# Calculate velocity

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm currently hanging on a problem who seems to be simple.
I Would like calculate a velocity of a developer team and I dont find the right formula.

Exemple :
If someone planned 10 hours(x) to do a job and his velocity(y) is 50%, so the right plannification is 20 Hours(Y).

- 10H * f(50%) => 20H
- 10H * f(100%) => 10H
- 10H * f(200%) => 5H
- z = x * f(y)

So, how to calculate function(y) :)
Many thanks

Comment: That terminology is odd, but it looks like you just mean $z=\frac xy$  where you must write the percentage, $y$, as a decimal number.  Thus $100\%$ corresponds to $y=1$, $50\%$ corresponds to $y=\frac 12$ and so on.  If you insist on leaving it as a percentage, then the formula would be $z=\frac {100x}{y}$.

Comment: Yes, in fact it was really simple. Thank you :)